# How to loop these pictures properly

Tags: php, foreach, joomla3.0

I am sure this is a simple principle of PHP, however it is one I am yet to learn. In principle the code works:

```
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<count($photos);$i++){
        if($photos[$i]->image != ""){
            if(JPATH_ROOT.'/images/'.$row->id.'/medium/'.$photos[$i]->image){
                if(!$photocount) {
                    $photocount = $photocount + 1;
                    $photoclass = "property_photo_main property_photo_main_" . $photocount; // First Photo Class
                }
                ?>
                <img src="<?php echo JURI::root()?>images<?php echo $row->id;?>/medium/<?php echo $photos[$i]->image?>" class="<?php echo $photoclass; ?>" alt="<?php echo $photos[$i]->image_desc;?>" title="<?php echo $photos[$i]->image_desc;?>"/>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

That outputs the images correctly, however the "Photo Count" does not increase and thus each photo gets the "First Photo Class" (property_photo_main_1). I fully appreciate that the problem here is because the count is not within the loop to print each photo, but as that is directly before that image output, where is the loop, and how can I implement that the count increases?

The HTML Output is:

```
                <img src="http://msa.eighttwentydesign.com/images/osproperty/properties/5/medium/51384100282240dc03c72cb44ce05eb9e56021d0c05.jpg" class="property_photo_main property_photo_main_1" alt="" title=""/>
                                    <img src="http://msa.eighttwentydesign.com/images/osproperty/properties/5/medium/51384100283f9f748ca556070c2d09553298dc26d8f.jpg" class="property_photo_main property_photo_main_1" alt="" title=""/>
                                    <img src="http://msa.eighttwentydesign.com/images/osproperty/properties/5/medium/51384100283b280e25f329d8cf1518bda4700b07765.jpg" class="property_photo_main property_photo_main_1" alt="" title=""/>
                                    <img src="http://msa.eighttwentydesign.com/images/osproperty/properties/5/medium/51384100283c801f9afb73308c7fd77a77ea00129bb.jpg" class="property_photo_main property_photo_main_1" alt="" title=""/>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never increment `$photocount` outside of that if. Also you never reset `$photoclass`

```
foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    if (!empty($photo->image)) {
        if (JPATH_ROOT.'/images/'.$row->id.'/medium/'.$photo->image) {

            if (!isSet($photocount))
                $photocount = 1;
            else
                $photocount++;

            $photoclass = "property_photo_main property_photo_main_" . $photocount;
            //HTML...
        }
    }
}
```

This way `$photoclass` gets reset in each iteration, also `$photocount` gets incremented by 1 if it has been set. I also took the liberty of using PHP's internal structures like [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/foreach) or [`empty`](http://www.php.net/empty), you can read about the usage in the manual.

Since `JPATH_ROOT.'/images/'.$row->id.'/medium/'.$photo->image` has no logic and is not null/false, it will always return true, maybe you meant to use something like [`file_exists`](http://www.php.net/file_exists)?

Using `!$photoclass` instead of `!isSet($photoclass)` will throw an undefined variable notice.

Comment: Thank you, comprehensive answer +1